# Remove top space UIScrollview in UIVIewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am implementing a UIViewController, it has tabbar, i have added scroll view but on iPhone X onwards, it is showing some extra top area.
[image]
How to remove that, so that image becomes full screen from top?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how your view hierarchy is set up, but assuming you have an UIImageView you should make sure that the top constraint is set to superview's top not to the safe area.

If you are working with storyboards you should go from this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

If your constraints are set correctly it could also be from having `automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets` set to true on your view controller.

You can change that from storyboard as shown bellow:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is from superview top, but status bar frame is causing the top space

Comment: @FastCoderz please check my updated answer, maybe your problem is caused by 'automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets' being set to true on your view controller